# Could give ethereum network upgrade solutions?

Tags: go-ethereum, network, upgrading

As we known, the ethereum have soft and hard fork to upgrade network. If we modify the private ethereum code, how to notify other nodes to upgrade their geth? What if they do not upgrade the network?  In the **technical** opinion, could you give some solutions to upgrade the ethereum network ? And is there any other solution to upgrade the ethereum solutions ?

Comment: It’s not clear what the question is. More context please.

Comment: @ivicaa thanks for your kind. If I modify the ethereum code, how to make other nodes come to an agreement about this upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

> If we modify the private ethereum code, how to notify other nodes to upgrade their geth?

This is mainly an organizational issue: Who maintains the code? How do you keep connected to the people/organizations running the node?

> What if they do not upgrade the network?

In this case the chain will fork.

> In the technical opinion, could you give some solutions to upgrade the ethereum network ?

In order to avoid a hard fork on upgrade, you can shutdown and upgrade all nodes at once (eventually feasible in a small private network) or define a block for the activation of the new feature so that all clients have enough time to upgrade before that block occurs.

Comment: A provider could provide two service: 1. check the version is the latest or not  2.download the latest setup program,  then the other nodes have two program: 1.go-ethereum  2. query process(or thread) , then query the provider the version situlation, if behind the latest version, then kill the go-ethereum and downlad the latest program, then setup and boot. How do you think of this?

Comment: This can work, but you're introducing strong centralization aspects with it. It depends on your usecase if this is bad or not. IMHO, I wouldn't automate this. Every node should explicitly check and decide to apply an update.

Comment: While, we don't want to see the case that it will occur two hard-fork If some nodes does not upgrade .

Comment: How to do what you said " define a block for the activation of the new feature so that all clients have enough time to upgrade before that block occurs " ??? Does it also need upgrade the network ?

Comment: if(currentBlock>=activationBlock) doFeatureX() <— like this.

Comment: Could you describe detailly?  What you said "if(currentBlock>=activationBlock) doFeatureX() " is the soft-fork? The nodes upgrade the soft fork first? Or where is the "if(currentBlock>=activationBlock) doFeatureX() " ?It does not exists in the before ethereum codes?

Comment: E.g. you change the code to add a totally new hard forking feature. But you don’t activate it immediately by inserting the if above. So clients have a grace period to update the software before the activation block occurs. Before the activation block the new software behaves like the old version, but at a specific block the switch triggers and it gets activated.